# What is the use of QuestionMark(?) in typescript variable?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have seen a scenario where in inside interpolation QuestionMark'?' is used with variable name. 
example : `current?.sample.innerSample`

I am not sure what it is used for. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: That is `safe navigation operator` and will be used in the template file

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`?.` is a safe navigation operator. It prevents object paths from `undefined` or `null reference` errors. For ex:

If you write `{{ data.somepropertyname }}` in the `template` file without defining the `data` member variable in `typescript` file, it will throw an error like below

> Cannot get `somepropertyname` of undefined

But if you write like this `{{data?.somepropertyname}}` it won't throw error

Check the example [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-untvbm)

Do comment and uncomment line numbers `8 & 9`, you will see the output in the console

Answer (score 4):

You can use [typescript online console](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) to check what does it mean. For example:

```js
var obj = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: null
        }
    }
};

var test = obj.a.b.c?.d;
console.log(test) // undefined
```

will be translated to:

```
"use strict";
var _a;
var obj = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: null
        }
    }
};
var test = (_a = obj.a.b.c) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.d;
console.log(test); // undefined
```

If you do not put ? it will result in `TypeError: Cannot read property 'd' of null` as c is null and d is not defined